# Getting Input inside <tr> tag within a tbody?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I know this has come up a lot of times and I have searched all over stack overflow. I have created a working Javascript function to get the `<input>` tag values within each row of a table.

However, when I include a `<tbody>` tag (which is required for row sorting), the Javascript code will not work and I have no idea why?

Please see the code below:

```
function writeXML() {

    var table = document.getElementById('table_assoc');
    alert(table);
    var rCount = document.getElementById('tbody_id').rows.length;
    alert(rCount);

    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var FILENAME = "c:/XML.xml";
    var file = fso.CreateTextFile(FILENAME, true);
    file.WriteLine('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n');
    file.WriteLine('<Seating_Plan>\n');

    for (var i = 1; i < rCount; i++) {

        var id = table.rows[i].cells[0].children[0].value; <-- Cant Find Table reference when <tbody> tag included.

        var deptcode = table.rows[i].cells[1].children[0].value;
        var name = table.rows[i].cells[2].children[0].value;
        var role = table.rows[i].cells[3].children[0].value;
        var desc = table.rows[i].cells[4].children[0].value;
        var image = table.rows[i].cells[5].children[0].value;
        var asdir = table.rows[i].cells[6].children[0].value;

        file.WriteLine('<Person id="' + id + '"><Dept>' + deptcode + '</Dept><Name>' + name + '</Name><Description>' + desc + '</Description><Role>' + role + '</Role><Image><image href="' + image + '"/></Image><AssociateDir><AssociateDir href="' + asdir + '"/></AssociateDir></Person>');
    }

    file.WriteLine('</Seating_Plan>');
    file.Close();
}
```

How do I get this to work when including a `tbody` tag?

==================================================================

**UPDATE:**

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Admin_Javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Header_Logo" ></div>
<div id="Header_Logo2">BMW UK</div>
<div id="Admin_Header">BMW LAYOUT EDITOR</div>
<div id="Admin_Nav">
<a id="btn_xml" class="Admin_Nav_Buttons">XML</a>
<a class="Admin_Nav_Buttons">Layout</a>
</div>
<div id="Admin_XML">
  <div id="XML_Buttons2">LOAD</div>
  <div id="XML_Buttons" onClick="writeXML()">SAVE</div>
  <span>&nbsp;</span>
  <p class="Admin_headers">Departments</p>
  <div id="Admin_Dept_Container"></div>
  <p class="Admin_headers">Associates</p>
  <div id="Admin_Associate_Container">

  <table id="table_assoc">
    <tbody id="tbody_id" >
    <tr><td><input value="ID"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input value="deptcode"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input value="name"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input value="role"></td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OP is *writing* to an XML file, which is not the source of the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also a collection of `tBodies`, you can get the one by its index:

```
var id = table.tBodies[0].rows[i].cells[0].children[0].value;
```

Comment: In the Developer Console for IE, when I run this, it cant find the value? Please see my update for the HTML... Thanks

Comment: I have decided to use PHP and Jquery to get the values from the table. Works far better for writing to Server and supports arrays.